# Correlation of categorical data to binomial response in R

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, correlation, categorical-data

I'm looking to analyze the correlation between a categorical input variable and a binomial response variable, but I'm not sure how to organize my data or if I'm planning the right analysis.

Here's my data table (variables explained below):

```
species<-c("Aaeg","Mcin","Ctri","Crip","Calb","Tole","Cfus","Mdes","Hill","Cpat","Mabd","Edim","Tdal","Tmin","Edia","Asus","Ltri","Gmor","Sbul","Cvic","Egra","Pvar")
scavenge<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1)
dung<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
pred<-c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
nectar<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
plant<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
blood<-c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
mushroom<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
loss<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0) #1 means yes, 0 means no
data<-cbind(species,scavenge,dung,pred,nectar,plant,blood,mushroom,loss)
data #check data table
```

**data table explanation**

I have individual species listed, and the next columns are their annotated feeding types. A 1 in a given column means yes, and a 0 means no. Some species have multiple feeding types, while some have only one feeding type. The response variable I am interested in is "loss," indicating loss of a trait. I'm curious to know if any of the feeding types predict or are correlated with the status of "loss."

**thoughts**

I wasn't sure if there was a good way to include feeding types as one categorical variable with multiple categories. I don't think I can organize it as a single variable with the types c("scavenge","dung","pred", etc...) since some species have multiple feeding types, so I split them up into separate columns and indicated their status as 1 (yes) or 0 (no). At the moment I was thinking of trying to use a log-linear analysis, but examples I find don't quite have comparable data... and I'm happy for suggestions.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: I think you're better off asking this question over at  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Can only post once every 40 minutes at my status... so I guess I'll leave this up for now.

Comment: Look at examples of logistic regression using `glm`. All of your variables except species are dichotomies. Don't use `cbind` to create your data. It converts everything to character vectors. Use `data.frame` instead.

Comment: Incorrect use of `cbind`. You just coerced all your values to character and teh `data` is now a matrix with a confusing name. Learn to use the data.frame function. It will be more efficient and prevent inadvertent coercion of classes. And don't name your objects  with R function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too little samples, you have 4 loss == 0  and 18 loss == 1. You will run into problems fitting a full logistic regression (i.e including all variables). I suggest testing for association for each feeding habit using a fisher test:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# function for the fisher test
FISHER <- function(x,y){
       FT = fisher.test(table(x,y))

data.frame(
       pvalue=FT$p.value,
       oddsratio=as.numeric(FT$estimate),
       lower_limit_OR = FT$conf.int[1],
       upper_limit_OR = FT$conf.int[2]
)
}
# define variables to test
FEEDING <- c("scavenge","dung","pred","nectar","plant","blood","mushroom")
# we loop through and test association between each variable and "loss"

results <- data[,FEEDING] %>% 
map_dfr(FISHER,y=data$loss) %>% 
add_column(var=FEEDING,.before=1)
```

You get the results for each feeding habit:

```
> results
       var      pvalue oddsratio lower_limit_OR upper_limit_OR
1 scavenge 0.264251538 0.1817465    0.002943469       2.817560
2     dung 1.000000000 1.1582683    0.017827686      20.132849
3     pred 0.263157895 0.0000000    0.000000000       3.189217
4   nectar 0.535201640 0.0000000    0.000000000       5.503659
5    plant 0.002597403       Inf    2.780171314            Inf
6    blood 1.000000000 0.0000000    0.000000000      26.102285
7 mushroom 0.337662338 5.0498688    0.054241930     467.892765
```

The pvalue is p-value from fisher.test, basically with an odds ratio > 1, the variable is positively associated with loss. Of all your variables, plant is the strongest and you can check:

```
> table(loss,plant)
    plant
loss  0  1
   0 18  0
   1  1  3
```

Almost all that are plant=1, are loss=1.. So with your current dataset, I think this is the best you can do. Should get a larger sample size to see if this still holds.

Comment: Thanks StupidWolf! And also dcarlson and 42 for advice on better data preparation.

Comment: Hi @Crawdaunt you're welcome! Good luck with your research!